# How do I create a Python dataclass from the schema of a PySpark DataFrame?

Tags: python, unit-testing, apache-spark, pyspark

I have relatively simple PySpark application that reads an input table, performs some transformations and outputs a new table.

I'd like to unit test this script using a dummy version of the input table with known mock data. However, because the input table has a rather complex, nested schema, manually creating a DataFrame for the input (e.g. directly in the test code or from a JSON-file) is rather cumbersome.

Typically, there are only a limited number of fields that are relevant for my test cases, so I'd like a solution that allows me easily create a DataFrame that sets the relevant fields to known values, and leaves the rest to some default which I don't have to specify.

One possible solution I thought of was to convert the DataFrame schema to a Python [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-dataclasses). This would allow me to create an instance of the class for each test case, manipulate the relevant fields using simple Python class attribute syntax and then write a DataFrame created from the test case dataclasses to the dummy table. In code, it would look something like:

```py
test_case1 = DataFrameClassRepresentation() # this class was generated from schema
test_case2 = DataFrameClassRepresentation()
test_case1.foo.bar = "some value"
test_case2.foo.baz = "some other value"

df = spark.createDataFrame([test_case1, test_case2])
df.writeTo("catalog.db.dummy_table")
```

Is there some built-in functionality or other simple way to generate such dataclasses from schemas in PySpark? Are there easier strategies for achieving what I want to do that I haven't thought of?

Comment: https://github.com/benchsci/tinsel  << This general purpose library looks amazing. Take a look at it. It precisely does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is quite what you're looking for because it requires you to define multiple dataclasses to match the intended schema (it would be more convenient to be able to initialize a dataclass using the schema itself, but I am not sure if this is possible). However, it does allow you to define default values and create test dataframes with the appropriate schema. I've also defined a `getSchema` function that extracts the pyspark schema from each instance of `DataFrameClassRepresentation`.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, BooleanType, FloatType, StringType, StructType, StructField

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()

@dataclass
class ColASchema:
    col1: int = 123
    col2: str = "xyz"

@dataclass
class ColBSchema:
    col3: int = 456
    col4: str = "abc"

@dataclass
class ColCSchema:
    col1: float = 3.14
    col2: str = "def"

@dataclass
class ColDSchema:
    col3: ColCSchema = ColCSchema()
    col4: float = 1.62
    
@dataclass
class DataFrameClassRepresentation:
    colA: ColASchema = ColASchema()
    colB: ColBSchema = ColBSchema()
    colC: ColCSchema = ColCSchema()
    colD: ColDSchema = ColDSchema()

python_to_pyspark_type_map = {
    'bool': BooleanType(),
    'int': IntegerType(),
    'float': FloatType(),
    'str': StringType(),
}

def getSchema(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return StructType(
            [StructField(k, python_to_pyspark_type_map[type(v).__name__], True) if not isinstance(v, dict)
            else StructField(k, getSchema(v), True)
            for k,v in d.items()]
        )
    else:
        return python_to_pyspark_type_map[type(d).__name__]
```

You could then create a test dataframe in the following way:

```
test_case1 = DataFrameClassRepresentation()
test_case2 = DataFrameClassRepresentation(ColASchema(1,"abc"))

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    asdict(test_case1), 
    asdict(test_case2)
], getSchema(asdict(test_case1)))

+----------+----------+-----------+-------------------+
|colA      |colB      |colC       |colD               |
+----------+----------+-----------+-------------------+
|{123, xyz}|{456, abc}|{3.14, def}|{{3.14, def}, 1.62}| # default values
|{1, abc}  |{456, abc}|{3.14, def}|{{3.14, def}, 1.62}|
+----------+----------+-----------+-------------------+

root
 |-- colA: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- colB: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col3: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- colC: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col1: float (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- colD: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col1: float (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col4: float (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Do you think this general purpose library could be of help? https://github.com/benchsci/tinsel

Comment: @user238607 thanks for the resource! that library looks very helpful for this use case. if i have some time, i'll take a look at that library and write up another answer

Comment: Ofcourse, you will have to basically invert that library's functionality, but could be a fun weekend project.

Comment: @DerekO Thanks for the input! Like you mention, it is not quite what I'm looking for, as I want a solution that generates a dataclass (with all nested dataclasses) dynamically from the schema. Your solution allows the use of Python classes for dynamically generating test data, but defining all the necessary dataclasses manually would still be quite a bit of work in my case

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `DataFrameClassRepresentation` class from scratch that sets class variables using the desired pyspark schema. There is a recursive method in the class that unpacks the schema no matter how many layers deep, converts it to a python dictionary with default values for each field (included nested fields), and then sets the class variables according to the dictionary. There are also internal class variables for defaults which isn't strictly necessary, but might be helpful for your use case.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, BooleanType, FloatType, StringType, StructType, StructField

class DataFrameClassRepresentation:
    _pyspark_default_by_type = {
        BooleanType(): True,
        IntegerType(): 0,
        FloatType(): 3.14,
        StringType(): 'abc',
    }
    _pyspark_to_python_type = {
        BooleanType(): 'bool',
        IntegerType(): 'int',
        FloatType(): 'float',
        StringType(): 'str',
    }

    def _generate_sample_data(self, pyspark_schema):
        if isinstance(pyspark_schema, StructType):
            return {
                field.name: self._pyspark_default_by_type[field.dataType] 
                if not isinstance(field.dataType, StructType)
                else self._generate_sample_data(field.dataType)
                for field in pyspark_schema
            }
        else:
            return {
                self._pyspark_to_python_type[pyspark_schema]: 
                self._pyspark_default_by_type[pyspark_schema]
            }
    
    def __init__(self, pyspark_schema, defaults_by_type=None):
        if defaults_by_type is None:
            defaults_by_type = {
                self._pyspark_to_python_type[t]:v for t,v
                in self._pyspark_default_by_type.items()
            }
        schema = self._generate_sample_data(pyspark_schema)
        for k, v in schema.items():
            if not isinstance(v, dict):
                setattr(self, k, defaults_by_type[type(v).__name__])
            else:
                setattr(self, k, v)
    
    def get_data(self) -> dict:
        """Return the data structure of a class instance"""
        return {key: value for key, value in self.__dict__.items()}
```

Then you can declare instances of the class for the purpose of unit testing, with the ability to set different fields as desired:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()

sample_schema = StructType([
StructField('colA', StructType([
     StructField('col1', FloatType(), True),
     StructField('col2', StringType(), True),
     StructField('col3', IntegerType(), True),
     StructField('colA1',
         StructType([
             StructField('col4', StringType(), True),
             StructField('col5', FloatType(), True),
         ]),
     ),
     ])),
 StructField('colB', IntegerType(), True),
 StructField('colC', BooleanType(), True)
 ])

test_case1 = DataFrameClassRepresentation(sample_schema)
test_case2 = DataFrameClassRepresentation(sample_schema)

test_case1.colA['col1'] = 10.00 # modify a nested field

test_df = spark.createDataFrame([
    test_case1.get_data(), 
    test_case2.get_data()
], sample_schema)
```

Below is a print out of `test_df` and its `schema`:

```
+---------------------------+----+----+
|colA                       |colB|colC|
+---------------------------+----+----+
|{10.0, abc, 0, {abc, 3.14}}|0   |true|
|{3.14, abc, 0, {abc, 3.14}}|0   |true|
+---------------------------+----+----+

root
 |-- colA: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col1: float (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col3: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- colA1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col4: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col5: float (nullable = true)
 |-- colB: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- colC: boolean (nullable = true)
```

Comment: did this answer end up helping?